# Picking n integers from n different sets summing to a given value

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of integers $\{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n\}$, where each integer is associated with a set $m_k\in\{-l_k,-l_k+1,\ldots,l_k\}$, I need to find all combinations $\{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\}$ that sum to a given integer $M$.

As an example, let's say the input is $\{1,3\}$ and $M=2$. This means that $m_1\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and $m_2\in\{-3,-2,\ldots,3\}$. The desired combinations are then:

$\{m_1,m_2\}=\{-1,3\},\{0,2\},\{1,1\}$.

For only two integers $l_1$ and $l_2$ this is easy, but a bit more involved for a general number. I have a brute force algorithm implemented which finds *all* possible combinations and then picks those with the right sum, but this quickly becomes too slow when the sets grow.

So I'm wondering if there is a fast algorithm to find these (doesn't have to be the fastest in existence if sacrificing a little speed gives one easier to implement)?

I'm sure this is a well known problem, but googling I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you view this problem as a forward directed graph, with each $m_i$ representing a column of nodes, one could create a more efficient algorithm using a dynamic programming approach.

Comment: Isn't what you have here just a variation on the Knapsack problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this might be a fun problem to solve, so I cranked out a solution for it based on the comment I made in the problem statement. The class representing the solution, which is in C++, can be found via the following link:

[Combinatorial Solution Class](https://github.com/choward1491/Bones/tree/master/src/Algorithms)

The main.cpp file can be written with the following example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CombinatorialSoln.hpp"


int main( int argc, char** argv ){

// Initialize combinatorial problem
CombinatorialSoln soln;
std::vector<int> iset {1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3};
soln.setIntegerSet(iset);

// Compute combinations
CombinatorialSoln::Combos combos = soln.computeCombinations(-5);

// print results
for(int i = 0; i < combos.size(); i++ ){
    combos[i].print();
}

// Print basic results
soln.showStatistics();

// Complete
return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is great! Now I wonder is there a way to either make this work either with half-integer l (so that e.g. l_1=3/2 and m_1 in {-3/2 -1/2 1/2 3/2}, or to make it so that one can switch m to "jumps of 2"; i.e. so that if e.g. l_1=5 it is possible using a flag to make m_1 in {-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5} ? (not part of the OP I know)

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't be too hard to modify the jump value to become an input that is used for each m set. It would only change some of the helper function logic in my mind.